# Evaluate analytic solution of the function

Tags: plotting, graphics, evaluation, list-manipulation, coordinate

[image]

Here, i have plotted a function and i would like to print the y coordinate values from the plot for the x-coordinate given below.
Coordinates in the sequence that every fourth y-coordinate should be repeated.

{ 0.,2000.,4000,6000,6000, 8000., 10000., 12000.}

```
analyticPlot = Plot[HeavisideTheta[9600 - 2 x], {x, 2400, 8400}]
[![sharp front][1]][1]
```

I have tried with the syntax like "evaluate and Table" but could not worked .

Answer (score 6):

What about

```
HeavisideTheta[9600 - 2 {0., 2000., 4000, 6000, 6000, 8000., 10000., 12000.}]
(*{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)
```

Comment: Yes, this could be done.  But given x coordinates are just for the example. Actualy required  is  more than 10000 coordinates.

Comment: Yes, this could be done.  But given x coordinates are just for the example. Actually required  is  more than 10000 coordinates. I have numerical solution and want to compare with analytic one. The numerical solution  is for the the x-coordinate. For the same x-coordinate need to print the y values which will be analytic solution.

Comment: You look for all the plotted x-values?

Comment: Yes. So that I can find the difference between analytic and numerical solution which will give me exact error value.

Comment: `p = Cases[analyticPlot, Line[p_] :> p, All] ;` gives all the plotted points

Comment: could you please explain the syntax?

Comment: `Cases` looks inside expression `analyticPlot` for `Line`- objects and returns the argument( points!) of Line.

Comment: HeavisideTheta[9600 - 2 {0., 2000., 4000, 6000, 6000, 8000., 10000., 12000.}]
(*{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}*)  this syntax gives the expected output. But could we do it automated.Like if the range is {0., 0.}, {0., 0.}, {1200., 0.}, {1200., 0.}, {2400., 0.}, {2400., 0.}, {3600., 0.}, {3600., 0.}, {4800., 0.}, {4800., 0.}, {6000., 0.}, {6000., 0.}, {7200., 0.}, {7200., 0.}, {8400., 0.}, {8400., 0.}, {9600., 0.}, {9600., 0.}, {10800., 0.}, {10800., 0.}, {12000., 0.}.Instead of writing whole range the syntax which gives every second coordinate is repeating eg.12000 is devided into 10 parts above.